# Deploying just HTML, CSS webpage to Tomcat

Tags: html, css, tomcat, web-deployment-project

I am just getting started on developing a **website**. All I have at the moment is **a HTML page** supported by a couple of **CSS stylesheets**.

Can I create **a WAR file from the HTML and CSS pages**? How do I **deploy them on to a Tomcat server**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here's my **setup**: I am on Ubuntu 9.10.

Now, Here's what I did.

1. Create a folder named "**tomcat6-myapp**" in **/usr/share**.
2. Create a folder "**myapp**" under **/usr/share/tomcat6-myapp**.
3. Copy the HTML file (that I need to deploy) to **/usr/share/tomcat6-myapp/myapp**. It must be named **index.html**.
4. Go to **/etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost**.
5. Create an xml file "**myapp.xml**" (i guess it must have the same name as the name of the folder in step 2) inside /etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost with the following contents.

   ```
   < Context path="/myapp" docBase="/usr/share/tomcat6-myapp/myapp" />
   ```
6. This xml is called the '**Deployment Descriptor**' which Tomcat reads and automatically deploys your app named "**myapp**".
7. Now go to **http://localhost:8080/myapp** in your browser - the index.html gets picked up by tomcat and is shown.

I hope this helps!

Comment: remember to insert into the xml `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Answer (score 165):

There is no real need to create a war to run it from Tomcat. You can follow these steps

1. Create a folder in webapps folder e.g. MyApp
2. Put your html and css in that folder and name the html file, which you want to be the starting page for your application, index.html
3. Start tomcat and point your browser to url "http://localhost:8080/MyApp". Your index.html page will pop up in the browser

Comment: I created a folder MyApp1 under /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/ and copied the html I am working with to MyApp1, renamed it to index.html.
http://localhost:8080/MyApp1 - gives 404 error.

Comment: Just downloaded tomcat 6, tried to the above on my windows XP and it worked. Since you are running it on linux (I guess from 'usr/share') I cannot recreate your scenario completely but try the following things - point your browser to localhost:8080. If you see the tomcat manager page, on the bottom left corner, click on servlet examples. Check the path of the resulting page. It points to index.html in servlets folder path of which is given by the page in browser. You need to set up your application on the same lines

Comment: I can confirm that gauravs method worked - i tried the same thing too.

Comment: @VandeGraff, that could be because you do not have read permissions. Usually files put under /usr/* have permission issues.... I put mine on /home/myAccount/installations/tomcat/webapps/myApp/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Here's my step in Ubuntu 16.04 and Tomcat 8.

1. Copy folder /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT to your folder.

   cp -r /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/{yourfolder}
2. Add your html, css, js, to your folder.
3. Open "http://localhost:8080/{yourfolder}" in browser

Notes:

1. If you using chrome web browser and did wrong folder before, then clean web browser's cache(or change another name) otherwise (sometimes) it always 404.
2. The folder META-INF with context.xml is needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a .war file you can deploy to a Tomcat instance using the Manager app, create a folder, put all your files in that folder (including an index.html file) move your terminal window into that folder, and execute the following command:

```
zip -r <AppName>.war *
```

I've tested it with Tomcat 8 on the Mac, but it should work anywhere

Answer (score 2):

(Answers are pretty old, so here's what worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 Tomcat9)
As root

```
  cd /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps
  mkdir -p myapp
  cd myapp
  cat >>index.html
  <html><body>MY SIMPLE PAGE </body></html>
  control-D # Press CONTROL+D to exit 'cat', create the file 'index.html'
  systemctl restart tomcat9
```

In browser, use URL: http://127.0.0.1/myapp

(Of course, you can make page fancier, add CSS, etc., etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a bit with older version of `Apache Tomcat (7.0.68)` running on `Windows Server 2012`, but this worked for me after a little bit of experimenting:

1. Create app folder with your static files (HTML, JS, CSS, assets, etc.).
2. Inside the folder create `META-INF` folder and add empty `MANIFEST.MF`.
3. *Optionally* zip the app folder and change the extension to `.war`.
4. Upload your app to Tomcat's `webapps` folder, either as a `.war` or just folder with your files.

Turned out, that `META-INF` with empty `MANIFEST.MF` file is enough for Tomcat to serve the app. No need to add `WEB-INF` or anything else (at least for my version of Tomcat).

Folder structure:

```
MyApp (folder)
|--index.html
|--app.js
|--app.css
|--assets (folder)
   |--logo.png
   |--...
|--META-INF (folder)
   |--MANIFEST.MF (empty file)
```