# How to deploy just HTML, CSS webpage to jetty?

Tags: html, css, web-applications, jetty

This is a question related to a similar question [Deploying just HTML, CSS webpage to Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954621/deploying-just-html-css-webpage-to-tomcat).

I followed the answers there and can successfully deploy HTML+CSS for tomcat. But now I have to run an web application powered by jetty instead of tomcat.

My question is, is it possible, and how to deploy just HTML and CSS to a custom location with jetty? (I am using Lubuntu/Ubuntu 14.04).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Jetty 9, the process is super simple.

In your `{jetty.base}/webapps/` directory create a sub-folder that will house your static file content and put your HTML/CSS in there.

Note that the name of the directory is used to determine the `contextPath` of your resulting webapp. (The special case name `ROOT` will deploy to `/`)

Eg:

```
$ cd /opt/web/mybase
$ mkdir -p webapps/public
$ cd webapps/public
$ cp -R /home/user/Downloads/static-web-content/ .
$ ls
index.html
flower.jpg
site.css
```

Now you can access that content via urls like `http://localhost/public/flower.jpg`