# index.html not found by Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, web.xml

I'm building maven project, with Spring and AngularJS.
The problem is that I got index.html under src/main/webapp/index.html
And I always get 404 not found when I trying to reach main page of my app.
Here's project structure:

[image]

And I also added

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

To web.xml but id doesn't help

**EDIT**:
I'm trying to reach the index.html page with:

```
localhost:8080/myapp
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954621/deploying-just-html-css-webpage-to-tomcat

Comment: Did you set 'web.xml' to your index file?

Comment: What URL are you using to get to the index.html and what does your web.xml look like?

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas Could you please clarify? How could I set web.xml to my index file?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis I use: http://localhost:8080/myapp/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Servlet returns "HTTP Status 404 The requested resource (/servlet) is not available"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377/servlet-returns-http-status-404-the-requested-resource-servlet-is-not-availa)