# How deploy .htm extension on a server?

Tags: html, angularjs, deployment, server, include

I want to learn AngularJs from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs 
but an example must be deployed a server. I don't know anything about it.

Please give me some hint about deploy  .htm extension file to a server.
Example url is following;

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_includes.htm

Comment: You should probably learn HTML first, and see how you can run these html files that you create on your local computer. you'll learn that you don't need server for client side languages like html or javascript(angular is essentially a javascript framework).

Comment: Mridul Kashyap Thanks for your advice .But I know html but this example different from others so that I ask this question.If you examine example you will see and understand issue.

Comment: in the example you gave, it says the 2 ways given at the top are used to embed html within another html page. it also says "Using AngularJS, we can embedded HTML pages within a HTML page using ng-include directive.". so do you want to try the server side methodologies as well before trying angular to embed the html within an html page?

Comment: @MridulKashyap you should see   foolowing statements end of page :Output
To run this example, you need to deploy textAngularJS.htm, main.htm and subjects.htm to a webserver. Open textAngularJS.htm using url of your server in a web browser. See the result.

Comment: make a folder on your desktop. put all three files in it. double click the `tryAngularJS.htm`. it should work.

Comment: I tried but it doesnt work.. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118388/discussion-between-mridul-kashyap-and-skynafo).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that they just mean placing the files somewhere inside the web root. The web root should be deployed by your local or remote server.

Example: 
Download and install MAMP. 
Set your root directory as the MAMP root directory in preferences. 
Now you can use your own paths -- just follow the example in the link you provided.

https://www.mamp.info/en/

Also, I'm of the opinion that it's good practice to at least use a local web server as opposed to running your website without one.

Comment: Thanks for your idea..But I think we dont need to download it because I have tomcat..Unfortunately I can' t deploy it to tomcat..

Comment: See this question here for a basic tomcat setup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954621/deploying-just-html-css-webpage-to-tomcat

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a webserver to test the code given in that example. `ng-include` using relative paths works fine. 
However, if you really want to use a webserver for other examples/projects, depending upon your OS, you can use *AMP. where * means

W for windows
L for linux

once you have it installed, place the files in `www` folder. and access it in browser using `http://localhost`

Comment: I question this: *W for windows L for linux and M for Mac* as MAMP is for Windows as well. MAMP stands for: My Apache - MySQL - PHP

Comment: @ketchupisred There. Fixed it.

Comment: Why do we meed PHP and MySQL? The files are static pages.

Comment: 1. The OP required that the files be served via a server -- but didn't specify which kind until later. 
2. MAMP is very easy to install and use compared to other servers that I've tried so that's why I recommended it. No one mentioned anything about utilizing PHP and MySQL; it just so happens that they are part of the MAMP package.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I add my app folder under

**D:\tomcat7\apache-tomcat-7.0.67-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.67\webapps**

after I run tomcat server .
 And run

**http://localhost:8080/an/ht.htm**
It is working :) Thanks @ketchupisred @Mridul Kashyap