# Hello,How can I run swagger editor on tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, localhost, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I searched but I didn't find the good explanation.

Comment: Swagger Editor is a static web page (HTML + JavaScript + CSS), so this question is the same as [Deploying just HTML, CSS webpage to Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954621/deploying-just-html-css-webpage-to-tomcat).

Answer (score 0):

Download swagger editor from: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/releases/download/v2.10.4/swagger-editor.zip
Extract it as a webapp.
You can configure it with config/default.json