# Tomcat Server wont load the Webpage

Tags: html, tomcat, deployment

Im trying to deploy my WebApplication on a TomCat 9.0.11.
Now everything went good so far, the artifact was deployed into the ROOT directory, but the page just wont load, and doesnt shows up my index.html? Does anybody see the error here? If i forgot something please tell me so i can add the missing stuff.

EDIT: I want to run the server on Windows first, later on Debian. The website should also be accesibile trough example.com not f.e. example.com/app (or for Windows localhost not localhost/app)

[TomcatConfiguration1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W53i.png)

[TomcatConfiguration2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCn3p.png)

[Artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iY3o.png)

[ServerLog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8jzK.png)

[TomcatServer after deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo1pd.png)

[Trying to open the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHFf1.png)

Greets
Lukas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploying just HTML, CSS webpage to Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954621/deploying-just-html-css-webpage-to-tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

i think project should be inside the webapp folder not inside root .Please attach log which can show us the context loading .
Or you can refer to this link:

[Deploying just HTML, CSS webpage to Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954621/deploying-just-html-css-webpage-to-tomcat)

Comment: Where can i find the log which shows the context loading?