# integration of back end and front end code running on different servers

Tags: javascript, html, css, spring-boot

I have web application in which for front end I am using java script, html, css put it on xampp server and for back end I am using spring boot framework and it work as API which run on tomcat server. So using API call I am showing information on the front-end, Is there any way that I can integrate both code together to run on same server either on tomcat or xampp

Comment: If you give https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask a quick read you'll see that you didn't provide most of the information needed for a "good question".  If you edit this and add in as much of that as you can, then you'll get much better responses.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your backend spring-boot server to serve web-content like html,js,css. I think [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) tutorial might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can host your Static website(Html/Css/Javascript) in Tomcat. Kindly, refer the below stackoverflow [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954621/deploying-just-html-css-webpage-to-tomcat) link.

Thanks